# Iframe request to download a PDF content and show in IE not working

Tags: python, html, apache, internet-explorer, iframe

I have an Iframe that loads the PDF content from the server and displays in the Iframe. This works well all browsers (Chrome, Firefox, and Safari) except IE.

IN IE, when I embed the URL in the Iframe

```
<iframe src="PDF content url" />
```

Its show following result in the Networks (Developer console)

```
url: "PDf content url", Protocol: "(Pending...)", Method: "GET", Result: "(Pending...)", Received: "0 B", Type: "(Pending...)" Taken: "(Pending...)", Initiator: "inner Html"
```

In the Microsoft developer network, the same issue has been reported

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cf6c6ee8-6643-4dc3-adb9-f5c845762fa5/how-to-debug-why-ie-11-silently-ignores-a-download?forum=iewebdevelopment

Can anyone explain, why this is happening or this is an expected behaviour in IE?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your PDF document generated by server side code dynamically? Use response.close() instead of response.flush()... Use a network sniffing tool to get the response headers and confirm that the content length and mime-type headers are as expected.... the IE security zone that the host is mapped to will also affect outcomes. Use the File>Properties menu in IE to determine which IE security zone the top host maps to. https responses are not cached when IE Options>Advance tab, "Do not save encrypted files to disk".

Comment: etc. PDF viewer applications like Adobe PDF viewer are Acitive X controls in IE. IE's ActiveX filtering settings will prevent display of ActiveX content in websites that map to the Internet or Restricted sites zones.